# Firebase ChildEventListener is not working for a long time in Java Admin SDK

Tags: android, firebase, jakarta-ee, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

In my current project data persistence is happens like this;

Android > Firebase database > Java EE Web application > MySQL database.

Writing data to Firebase from android is done and it is working perfectly. In the next step, which is read from firebase then write to MySQL I am using Firebase Admin SDK.

My plan was to set up a `ServletContextListener` to the web application to tiger on deploying at Glassfish server, within that listener I set up some `childeventListeners` to some database references on firebase database using following codes.

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    try {

        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        InputStream serviceAccount = classLoader
                .getResourceAsStream("/XXXXXX/firebase_private_key.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://xxxxxxxxxxx.com").build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();


        // SET UP LISTENER
        DatabaseReference ref = firebaseDatabase.getReference("XXXXXXXXX");
        ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot arg0, String arg1) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot arg0, String arg1) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot arg0, String arg1) {
                   storeData(arg0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError arg0) {
            }
            });
}
```

Everything is working nicely as I supposed, but only for few hours. `ChildeventListeners` are disabling automatically.

I need to work that listeners forever to keep syncing data between firebase database to MySQL database.

Am I missing something or, am I misusing `ChildEventListeners` ? Rather using above process, implementing a scheduled syncing process using `EJB Timers` would be a good practice?

Comment: Is there any logging output that happens when the connection gets dropped? To get the logging, see https://medium.com/@hiranya911/logging-in-java-libraries-for-firebase-and-google-cloud-platform-f8742493b73f

Comment: Also: don't leave `onCancelled` empty, as you may be missing important information that way. The minimal implementation is public void `onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`